# Will android recycle back activity in foreground process for top activity use when lack memory

Tags: android, memory

Will android recycle back activities in foreground process for top activity use when lack memory.

When android device memory lack , system will recycle process for memory. Forground process is hardly to be recycled. However , if memory is very little , will android recycle back activities in the process?

I make a test app . It use more memory when clicking a button . It crashes when it match it's max memory. But the system is not lacking memory , it's a wrong test. So how could simulation lacking memory?